To remove the create sequelize model from OUTPUT INSERTED
My Model
function serviceDelivery() {
  const serviceDelivery = sequelize.define(
    "ServiceDelivery",
    {
      svcDevId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      proEngId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      contactId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      serviceId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      statusId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      completedBy: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: true,
      },
      coachComplete: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      channelComplete: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: true,
      },
      createdDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      lastModifiedDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      completeDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      comment: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(500),
        allowNull: true,
      },
      followupDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        allowNull: true,
      },
      assignedCoach: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
      },
    },
    {
      tableName: "service_delivery",
      timestamps: true,
      createdAt: "createdDate",
      updatedAt: "lastModifiedDate",
    }
  );
  return serviceDelivery;
}

module.exports = serviceDelivery;


My Request
const serviceDelivery = require("../models/service-delivery");
const serviceDeliveryModel = serviceDelivery();
const user_data = { 
        proEngId: "8006420",
        contactId: "1701303",
        serviceId: "5000364", 
        statusId: "1000004"
       }
const result = await serviceDeliveryModel.create(user_data,  
          {
            returning: false, // Override default options
        
          });
console.log(result);

I'm setting the returning false because, I have trigger on my service_delivery table.
On setting returning false, it is throws the following error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at Query.handleInsertQuery (/Users/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/query.js:310:39)


The SQL command getting executed if there is returning false.
Executing (default): INSERT INTO [service_delivery] ([proEngId],[contactId][serviceId],[statusId],[createdDate],[lastModifiedDate]) VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5);

Dialect: mssql
Sequelize version: 6.35.2
Node.js version: v18.16.0
If anyone has some workaround for having triggers enabled and calling create with returning false or returning true, then please help me out.

Seems like there should be a comma here somewhere, ...[contactId][serviceId]...

What's the getInsertIdField?

On setting returning false, it is throws the following error.
id = id || results && results[0][this.getInsertIdField()];
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
